# Why am I getting value error in viewing a file?

Tags: python, file, valueerror

I am trying to create a password manager in Python and I am getting an Value Error. Below is my code that I've written for the password manager. It uses inputs for password.

```
def view():
    with open("passwords.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f.readline():
            data = (line.rstrip())
            user, passw = data.split("|")
            print("User: ", user, "password", passw)

def add():
    name = input("Account Name: ")
    pwd = input("Password:" )
    with open("passwords.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(name + "|" + pwd + "\n")

while True:
    mode = input ("Would you like to add a new password or view existing ones (view, add). Press q to quit").lower()
    if mode == "q":
        quit()
    if mode == "view":
        view()
    elif mode == "add":
        add()
    else:
        print("You have entered an invalid mode")
        continue
```

Here is the error I'm getting when running and entering inputs:

```
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Python\exercises\passwordmanag.py", line 22, in <module>
    view()
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Python\exercises\passwordmanag.py", line 8, in view
    user, passw = data.split("|")
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Can someone please help me out and guide me on how to fix this error?

Thank you.

Comment: Your "passwords.txt" contains a line without a `|`. Open it in a text editor.

Comment: Add `print(data)` before that line to see which line of the file caused the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def view():
    with open("passwords.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            data = (line.rstrip())
            user, passw = data.split("|")
            print("User: ", user, "password", passw)

def add():
    name = input("Account Name: ")
    pwd = input("Password:" )
    with open("passwords.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(name + "|" + pwd + "\n")

while True:
    mode = input ("Would you like to add a new password or view existing ones (view, add). Press q to quit").lower()
    if mode == "q":
        quit()
    if mode == "view":
        view()
    elif mode == "add":
        add()
    else:
        print("You have entered an invalid mode")
        continue
```

Context: You were trying to read each character of the line rather than reading each line therefore it was giving you an error when trying to split.